# Select rows using mapping table with JPA

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I do not know how to implement the query below in jpa, so please help.

```
select t.*
from team t
join team_memeber tm
  on t.team_id = tm.team_id and tm.member_id = ?
```

The related entities are as follows.

```
public class Team {
  @Id
  int teamId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "teamId")
  Set<TeamMember> members = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class TeamMember {
  @Id
  int id;

  int teamId;

  int memberId;
}
```

Comment: What is `tag_id` ? Also I think you should have `ManyToOne` associations in your `TeamMember` entity (bidirectional relation) instead of IDs as `int` .

Comment: Sorry, I should write ```member_id```, but I wrote ```tag_id``` incorrectly. And I have to maintain unidirectional relation. Please let me know if there is a way to solve this without changing the relation.

Comment: OK, so I guess you could simply write a JPQL query like : `select t from Team t join t.members m where m.memberId = ?1`